# High charts error #19

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to plot chart for series, time on xAxis and numbers on yAxis.
The code I'm using is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: #B09730">Alert# ' + s[0] + '</span>'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Start Date: ' + s[3] + " End Date: " + s[4] + "(" + s[5] + ")"
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b',
                day: '%d'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Alert Size'
            },
            min: 0,
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f}'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Point',
            // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
            // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
            // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
            data: [
                [1441293135000, 50],
                [1441293195000, 100],
                [1441293255000, 150],
                [1441293315000, 250],
                [1441293375000, 50]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

This code works fine on chrome, but on mozilla firefox does not work, it gives me the error:

> uncaught exception: Highcharts error #19: www.highcharts.com/errors/19

Any help?

Comment: Have you read what the error says? It tells you the issue, and how to fix it: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/19

Comment: I read it, but couldn't understand it, or how to fix it? do u have any idea about it?

Comment: I have the same problem, but how can I know in front, if there will be too many ticks, when I do not know the size of the chart, as it may be responsive, or dynamic - so the chart width may be dependant on the browser width?

Comment: @Asped I have the same problem as you, but I put the static data to make it more clear

Comment: Please,, anyone help!!

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: Well, for me it works properly: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/b5eLgno8/ ensure if s variable is correct.

Comment: s variable is correct, and it is array, it works in chrome, but in mozilla does not, I'm so confused, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works, the problem was in the css properties of my html element, my html code was like this:

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; margin:5px;"> 
      <span id="container" style="width: 850px;  margin: 0 auto;overflow:scroll"></span>
    </div>
```

I just removed overflow property, and it works fine, my html became like this:

```
   <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; margin:5px;"> 
      <span id="container" style="width: 850px;  margin: 0 auto;"></span> 
   </div>
```

Comment: @Asped see this, it might help you.